# Appropriate Usage of Ref Keyword

Tags: c#, api, rest

As part of a .NET Core class library, I'm designing a [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) to communicate with a REST API. Let's assume this client deals with objects of type `MyObject`, and that this type has an internal constructor. To get to the point, I'm wondering whether it'd be appropriate to use `ref` parameters on update and delete methods so that remote changes are applied to the operands immediately, rather than requiring API users to manually keep track of state. This is especially concerning to me in the case of a delete, where I wouldn't want users to be able to erroneously use an instance of `MyObject` once it's been deleted remotely. Granted, I could introduce error handling to deal with that, but I wasn't sure whether `ref` would be a cleaner solution.

So which would be preferable? This:

```
public class MyClient
{        
    public MyObject UpdateObject(MyObject myObject, ParameterObject parameters)
    {
        return RemoteUpdate(myObject, parameters);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class MyClient
{        
    public void UpdateObject(ref MyObject myObject, ParameterObject parameters)
    {
        myObject = RemoteUpdate(myObject, parameters);
    }
}
```

And likewise for delete. This:

```
public class MyClient
{        
    public void DeleteObject(MyObject myObject)
    {
        RemoteDelete(myObject);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class MyClient
{        
    public void DeleteObject(ref MyObject myObject)
    {
        RemoteDelete(myObject, parameters);
        myObject = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a decent enough API. although I think ultimately this is question will generate opinion-based answers though.

Comment: Just in passing... In general, REST services are expected to be completely stateless server-side. Generally, that means that the client is expected to maintain at least some state. To me, `ref` makes no sense. What happens if you create a signature like that and exercise it with a REST client? To me, if you want to get this information back to the client, return it explicitly in the returned payload. Remember, in a system like this, there's no concept of object identity

Comment: This will be opinion-based, so IMO don't use `ref` unless you have to. Look at how .NET SDK is made. `ref` is only used for interopt and TryParse, TryGetValue etc. If I were you I would return `MyObject`from the methods (not delete) `public MyObject UpdateObject(MyObject myObject, ParameterObject parameters)`